# Parsing GeoJSON in Python?

Tags: python, geojson

I want to try and split a GeoJSON FeatureCollection into the individual features. So that the name of the file I write to is the "ED_ID" field. So far I can only read the JSON.

I am new to python and programming in general.

```
import json
with open('ded.geojson') as f:
data = json.load(f)
```

My data looks like this I have pulled out most of the coordinate data and this is one feature the file contains multiple features which I wish to separate.

```
 {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"OBJECTID_12":3001,"ED_ID":"197023","ED_ENGLISH":"BREEDOGE","ED_GAEILGE":" ","COUNTY":"ROSCOMMON","CONTAE":"Ros Comáin","PROVINCE":"Connacht","CENTROID_X":"573408","CENTROID_Y":"796269","OBJECTID":927,"ED_ID_1":"197023","FIRST_COUNTY":"ROSCOMMON","FIRST_CONTAE":"Ros Comáin","FIRST_PROVINCE":"Connacht","FIRST_ED_ENGLISH":"BREEDOGE","FIRST_ED_GAEILGE":" ","MaxSimpTol":100,"MinSimpTol":100,"GUID":"2AE196291AE513A3E055000000000001","ObjectID_1":927,"Shape__Area":0.00260221958729151,"Shape__Length":0.361585766792224},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-8.40526490835231,53.926763221445],[-8.39132968800989,53.9252835371864],[-8.38738628086417,53.9256611572713],[-8.38443774016629,53.927271794708],[-8.37396157235263,53.9250928131867]]]}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should do what you want. There might be a slightly more elegant way to write it, but I understand your request to pull out each polygon into their own file.

```
import json
import os

directory = "c:/temp/json"

with open(os.path.join(directory, 'geo.json')) as f:
    d = json.load(f)

for part in d['features']:
    fName = part["properties"]["ED_ID"]
    output = {"type":'FeatureCollection',
        "features": [{       
            "type": 'Feature',
            "properties": part['properties'],
            "geometry": {
                "type": 'Polygon',
                "coordinates": part['geometry']['coordinates']
            }
            }]
        }
    with open(os.path.join(directory, fName + ".json"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
        json.dump(output, f_out, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    print(json.dumps(output))

#print(d)
```